# Reading the target of a .lnk file in Python?

Tags: python, directory, shortcut, target, lnk

I'm trying to read the target file/directory of a shortcut (`.lnk`) file from Python. Is there a headache-free way to do it? The spec is way over my head.
I don't mind using Windows-only APIs.

My ultimate goal is to find the `"(My) Videos"` folder on Windows XP and Vista. On XP, by default, it's at `%HOMEPATH%\My Documents\My Videos`, and on Vista it's `%HOMEPATH%\Videos`. However, the user can relocate this folder. In the case, the `%HOMEPATH%\Videos` folder ceases to exists and is replaced by `%HOMEPATH%\Videos.lnk` which points to the new `"My Videos"` folder. And I want its absolute location.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

**Create a shortcut using Python (via WSH)**

```
import sys
import win32com.client 

shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
shortcut = shell.CreateShortCut("t:\\test.lnk")
shortcut.Targetpath = "t:\\ftemp"
shortcut.save()
```

**Read the Target of a Shortcut using Python (via WSH)**

```
import sys
import win32com.client 

shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
shortcut = shell.CreateShortCut("t:\\test.lnk")
print(shortcut.Targetpath)
```

Comment: Thank goodness I found this! I was about to give up and write a vbs script and call it from my python script. This is much better. +1

Comment: For target arguments, shortcut.Arguments

Comment: strange. I always get empty string back when calling `print(shortcut.Targetpath)`. I'm doing that to a folder. Does this method also apply to folders?

Comment: Same for me. If i compare the file contents created by windows with the one created by this method there is at least much more information in the version create by windows. Also the Targetpath yields some output for the windows version.

Comment: How can I add arguments to `shortcut.Targetpath`

Comment: Dose this support utf8? if Targetpath has utf8 character

Answer (score 26):

I know this is an older thread but I feel that there isn't much information on the method that uses the link specification as noted in the original question.

My shortcut target implementation could not use the win32com module and after a lot of searching, decided to come up with my own.  Nothing else seemed to accomplish what I needed under my restrictions.  Hopefully this will help other folks in this same situation.

It uses the binary structure Microsoft has provided for [MS-SHLLINK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd871305.aspx).

```
import struct

path = 'myfile.txt.lnk'    
target = ''

with open(path, 'rb') as stream:
    content = stream.read()
    # skip first 20 bytes (HeaderSize and LinkCLSID)
    # read the LinkFlags structure (4 bytes)
    lflags = struct.unpack('I', content[0x14:0x18])[0]
    position = 0x18
    # if the HasLinkTargetIDList bit is set then skip the stored IDList 
    # structure and header
    if (lflags & 0x01) == 1:
        position = struct.unpack('H', content[0x4C:0x4E])[0] + 0x4E
    last_pos = position
    position += 0x04
    # get how long the file information is (LinkInfoSize)
    length = struct.unpack('I', content[last_pos:position])[0]
    # skip 12 bytes (LinkInfoHeaderSize, LinkInfoFlags, and VolumeIDOffset)
    position += 0x0C
    # go to the LocalBasePath position
    lbpos = struct.unpack('I', content[position:position+0x04])[0]
    position = last_pos + lbpos
    # read the string at the given position of the determined length
    size= (length + last_pos) - position - 0x02
    temp = struct.unpack('c' * size, content[position:position+size])
    target = ''.join([chr(ord(a)) for a in temp])
```

Comment: wonderful.  Hopefully we can get this put into a full object, then into the standard library

Comment: Modified to support unicode & local encoding https://gist.github.com/Winand/997ed38269e899eb561991a0c663fa49

Comment: I was looking forever for this answer. I was about to do the same thing myself!

Answer (score 12):

Alternatively, you could try using [SHGetFolderPath()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762181(VS.85).aspx).  The following code might work, but I'm not on a Windows machine right now so I can't test it.

```
import ctypes

shell32 = ctypes.windll.shell32

# allocate MAX_PATH bytes in buffer
video_folder_path = ctypes.create_string_buffer(260)

# 0xE is CSIDL_MYVIDEO
# 0 is SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT
# If you want a Unicode path, use SHGetFolderPathW instead
if shell32.SHGetFolderPathA(None, 0xE, None, 0, video_folder_path) >= 0:
    # success, video_folder_path now contains the correct path
else:
    # error
```

Comment: This seems like it should work, but ctypes is saying it can't call that function (as well as several other documented shell32 functions). I'm running Python 2.6 on Windows XP SP3.

Comment: Works, with two issues.
1) The function is actually called SHGetFolderPathA (notice the A at the end)
2) The "My Videos" folder's ID is 0xE. 0x37 is the "Public/Common Videos" folder.
I got it to work. Thanks!

Comment: Good catch on those - I fixed the answer.

Answer (score 11):

Basically call the Windows API directly. Here is a good example found after Googling:

```
import os, sys
import pythoncom
from win32com.shell import shell, shellcon

shortcut = pythoncom.CoCreateInstance (
  shell.CLSID_ShellLink,
  None,
  pythoncom.CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
  shell.IID_IShellLink
)
desktop_path = shell.SHGetFolderPath (0, shellcon.CSIDL_DESKTOP, 0, 0)
shortcut_path = os.path.join (desktop_path, "python.lnk")
persist_file = shortcut.QueryInterface (pythoncom.IID_IPersistFile)
persist_file.Load (shortcut_path)

shortcut.SetDescription ("Updated Python %s" % sys.version)
mydocs_path = shell.SHGetFolderPath (0, shellcon.CSIDL_PERSONAL, 0, 0)
shortcut.SetWorkingDirectory (mydocs_path)

persist_file.Save (shortcut_path, 0)
```

This is from http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/create-a-shortcut.html.

You can search for "python ishelllink" for other examples.

Also, the API reference helps too: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774950(VS.85).aspx

Comment: Just want to mention that this pythoncom approach is using ASCII api on Python2, and would cause troubles if the path lnk pointed to contains unicode chars. The WSH approach is using WCHAR api and do not have this issue.

Answer (score 8):

I also realize this question is old, but I found the answers to be most relevant to my situation.

Like Jared's answer, I also could not use the win32com module.  So Jared's use of the binary structure from [MS-SHLLINK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd871305.aspx) got me part of the way there. I needed read shortcuts on both Windows and Linux, where the shortcuts are created on a samba share by Windows.  Jared's implementation didn't quite work for me, I think only because I encountered some different variations on the shortcut format.  But, it gave me the start I needed (thanks Jared).

So, here is a class named MSShortcut which expands on Jared's approach. However, the implementation is only Python3.4 and above, due to using some pathlib features added in Python3.4

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3

# Link Format from MS: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd871305.aspx
# Need to be able to read shortcut target from .lnk file on linux or windows.
# Original inspiration from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/397125/reading-the-target-of-a-lnk-file-in-python

from pathlib import Path, PureWindowsPath
import struct, sys, warnings

if sys.hexversion < 0x03040000:
    warnings.warn("'{}' module requires python3.4 version or above".format(__file__), ImportWarning)


# doc says class id = 
#    00021401-0000-0000-C000-000000000046
# requiredCLSID = b'\x00\x02\x14\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\xC0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x46'
# Actually Getting: 
requiredCLSID   = b'\x01\x14\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xC0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x46'  # puzzling

class ShortCutError(RuntimeError):
    pass


class MSShortcut():
    """
    interface to Microsoft Shortcut Objects.  Purpose:
    - I need to be able to get the target from a samba shared on a linux machine
    - Also need to get access from a Windows machine.
    - Need to support several forms of the shortcut, as they seem be created differently depending on the 
      creating machine.
    - Included some 'flag' types in external interface to help test differences in shortcut types

    Args:
        scPath (str): path to shortcut

    Limitations:
        - There are some omitted object properties in the implementation. 
          Only implemented / tested enough to recover the shortcut target information. Recognized omissions:
          - LinkTargetIDList
          - VolumeId structure (if captured later, should be a separate class object to hold info)
          - Only captured environment block from extra data 
        - I don't know how or when some of the shortcut information is used, only captured what I recognized, 
          so there may be bugs related to use of the information
        - NO shortcut update support (though might be nice)
        - Implementation requires python 3.4 or greater
        - Tested only with Unicode data on a 64bit little endian machine, did not consider potential endian issues

    Not Debugged:
        - localBasePath - didn't check if parsed correctly or not.
        - commonPathSuffix
        - commonNetworkRelativeLink

    """

    def __init__(self, scPath):
        """
        Parse and keep shortcut properties on creation
        """
        self.scPath = Path(scPath)

        self._clsid = None
        self._lnkFlags = None
        self._lnkInfoFlags = None
        self._localBasePath = None
        self._commonPathSuffix = None
        self._commonNetworkRelativeLink = None
        self._name = None
        self._relativePath = None
        self._workingDir = None
        self._commandLineArgs = None
        self._iconLocation = None
        self._envTarget = None

        self._ParseLnkFile(self.scPath)  


    @property
    def clsid(self): 
        return self._clsid

    @property
    def lnkFlags(self): 
        return self._lnkFlags

    @property
    def lnkInfoFlags(self): 
        return self._lnkInfoFlags

    @property
    def localBasePath(self): 
        return self._localBasePath

    @property
    def commonPathSuffix(self): 
        return self._commonPathSuffix

    @property
    def commonNetworkRelativeLink(self): 
        return self._commonNetworkRelativeLink

    @property
    def name(self): 
        return self._name    

    @property
    def relativePath(self): 
        return self._relativePath    

    @property
    def workingDir(self): 
        return self._workingDir    

    @property
    def commandLineArgs(self): 
        return self._commandLineArgs    

    @property
    def iconLocation(self): 
        return self._iconLocation    

    @property
    def envTarget(self): 
        return self._envTarget    


    @property
    def targetPath(self):
        """
        Args:
            woAnchor (bool): remove the anchor (\\server\path or drive:) from returned path.

        Returns:
            a libpath PureWindowsPath object for combined workingDir/relative path
            or the envTarget

        Raises:
            ShortCutError when no target path found in Shortcut
        """
        target = None
        if self.workingDir:
            target = PureWindowsPath(self.workingDir)
            if self.relativePath:
                target = target / PureWindowsPath(self.relativePath)
            else: target = None

        if not target and self.envTarget:
            target = PureWindowsPath(self.envTarget)

        if not target:
            raise ShortCutError("Unable to retrieve target path from MS Shortcut: shortcut = {}"
                               .format(str(self.scPath)))  

        return target    

    @property
    def targetPathWOAnchor(self):
        tp = self.targetPath
        return tp.relative_to(tp.anchor)




    def _ParseLnkFile(self, lnkPath):        
        with lnkPath.open('rb') as f:
            content = f.read()

            # verify size  (4 bytes)
            hdrSize = struct.unpack('I', content[0x00:0x04])[0]
            if hdrSize != 0x4C:
                raise ShortCutError("MS Shortcut HeaderSize = {}, but required to be = {}: shortcut = {}"
                                   .format(hdrSize, 0x4C, str(lnkPath)))

            # verify LinkCLSID id (16 bytes)            
            self._clsid = bytes(struct.unpack('B'*16, content[0x04:0x14]))
            if self._clsid != requiredCLSID:
                raise ShortCutError("MS Shortcut ClassID = {}, but required to be = {}: shortcut = {}"
                                   .format(self._clsid, requiredCLSID, str(lnkPath)))        

            # read the LinkFlags structure (4 bytes)
            self._lnkFlags = struct.unpack('I', content[0x14:0x18])[0]
            #logger.debug("lnkFlags=0x%0.8x" % self._lnkFlags)
            position = 0x4C

            # if HasLinkTargetIDList bit, then position to skip the stored IDList structure and header
            if (self._lnkFlags & 0x01):
                idListSize = struct.unpack('H', content[position:position+0x02])[0]
                position += idListSize + 2

            # if HasLinkInfo, then process the linkinfo structure  
            if (self._lnkFlags & 0x02):
                (linkInfoSize, linkInfoHdrSize, self._linkInfoFlags, 
                 volIdOffset, localBasePathOffset, 
                 cmnNetRelativeLinkOffset, cmnPathSuffixOffset) = struct.unpack('IIIIIII', content[position:position+28])

                # check for optional offsets
                localBasePathOffsetUnicode = None
                cmnPathSuffixOffsetUnicode = None
                if linkInfoHdrSize >= 0x24:
                    (localBasePathOffsetUnicode, cmnPathSuffixOffsetUnicode) = struct.unpack('II', content[position+28:position+36])

                #logger.debug("0x%0.8X" % linkInfoSize)
                #logger.debug("0x%0.8X" % linkInfoHdrSize)
                #logger.debug("0x%0.8X" % self._linkInfoFlags)
                #logger.debug("0x%0.8X" % volIdOffset)
                #logger.debug("0x%0.8X" % localBasePathOffset)
                #logger.debug("0x%0.8X" % cmnNetRelativeLinkOffset)
                #logger.debug("0x%0.8X" % cmnPathSuffixOffset)
                #logger.debug("0x%0.8X" % localBasePathOffsetUnicode)
                #logger.debug("0x%0.8X" % cmnPathSuffixOffsetUnicode)

                # if info has a localBasePath
                if (self._linkInfoFlags & 0x01):
                    bpPosition = position + localBasePathOffset

                    # not debugged - don't know if this works or not
                    self._localBasePath = UnpackZ('z', content[bpPosition:])[0].decode('ascii')
                    #logger.debug("localBasePath: {}".format(self._localBasePath))

                    if localBasePathOffsetUnicode:
                        bpPosition = position + localBasePathOffsetUnicode
                        self._localBasePath = UnpackUnicodeZ('z', content[bpPosition:])[0]
                        self._localBasePath = self._localBasePath.decode('utf-16')               
                        #logger.debug("localBasePathUnicode: {}".format(self._localBasePath))

                # get common Path Suffix
                cmnSuffixPosition = position + cmnPathSuffixOffset               
                self._commonPathSuffix = UnpackZ('z', content[cmnSuffixPosition:])[0].decode('ascii')
                #logger.debug("commonPathSuffix: {}".format(self._commonPathSuffix))
                if cmnPathSuffixOffsetUnicode:
                    cmnSuffixPosition = position + cmnPathSuffixOffsetUnicode
                    self._commonPathSuffix = UnpackUnicodeZ('z', content[cmnSuffixPosition:])[0]
                    self._commonPathSuffix = self._commonPathSuffix.decode('utf-16')               
                    #logger.debug("commonPathSuffix: {}".format(self._commonPathSuffix))


                # check for CommonNetworkRelativeLink
                if (self._linkInfoFlags & 0x02):
                    relPosition = position + cmnNetRelativeLinkOffset
                    self._commonNetworkRelativeLink = CommonNetworkRelativeLink(content, relPosition)

                position += linkInfoSize 

            # If HasName
            if (self._lnkFlags & 0x04):
                (position, self._name) = self.readStringObj(content, position)
                #logger.debug("name: {}".format(self._name))     

            # get relative path string
            if (self._lnkFlags & 0x08):
                (position, self._relativePath) = self.readStringObj(content, position)
                #logger.debug("relPath='{}'".format(self._relativePath))

            # get working dir string
            if (self._lnkFlags & 0x10):
                (position, self._workingDir) = self.readStringObj(content, position)
                #logger.debug("workingDir='{}'".format(self._workingDir))

            # get command line arguments
            if (self._lnkFlags & 0x20):
                (position, self._commandLineArgs) = self.readStringObj(content, position)
                #logger.debug("commandLineArgs='{}'".format(self._commandLineArgs))

            # get icon location
            if (self._lnkFlags & 0x40):
                (position, self._iconLocation) = self.readStringObj(content, position)
                #logger.debug("iconLocation='{}'".format(self._iconLocation))

            # look for environment properties             
            if (self._lnkFlags & 0x200):
                while True:
                    size = struct.unpack('I', content[position:position+4])[0]
                    #logger.debug("blksize=%d" % size)
                    if size==0: break

                    signature = struct.unpack('I', content[position+4:position+8])[0]
                    #logger.debug("signature=0x%0.8x" % signature)     

                    # EnvironmentVariableDataBlock          
                    if signature == 0xA0000001:  

                        if (self._lnkFlags & 0x80): # unicode
                            self._envTarget = UnpackUnicodeZ('z', content[position+268:])[0]
                            self._envTarget = self._envTarget.decode('utf-16')
                        else:
                            self._envTarget = UnpackZ('z', content[position+8:])[0].decode('ascii')

                        #logger.debug("envTarget='{}'".format(self._envTarget))

                    position += size


    def readStringObj(self, scContent, position):
        """ 
        returns:
            tuple: (newPosition, string)
        """
        strg = ''
        size = struct.unpack('H', scContent[position:position+2])[0]
        #logger.debug("workingDirSize={}".format(size))
        if (self._lnkFlags & 0x80): # unicode
            size *= 2
            strg = struct.unpack(str(size)+'s', scContent[position+2:position+2+size])[0]
            strg = strg.decode('utf-16')               
        else:
            strg = struct.unpack(str(size)+'s', scContent[position+2:position+2+size])[0].decode('ascii')
        #logger.debug("strg='{}'".format(strg))
        position += size + 2 # 2 bytes to account for CountCharacters field

        return (position, strg)




class CommonNetworkRelativeLink():

    def __init__(self, scContent, linkContentPos):

        self._networkProviderType = None
        self._deviceName = None
        self._netName = None

        (linkSize, flags, netNameOffset, 
         devNameOffset, self._networkProviderType) = struct.unpack('IIIII', scContent[linkContentPos:linkContentPos+20])

        #logger.debug("netnameOffset = {}".format(netNameOffset))
        if netNameOffset > 0x014:
            (netNameOffsetUnicode, devNameOffsetUnicode) = struct.unpack('II', scContent[linkContentPos+20:linkContentPos+28])
            #logger.debug("netnameOffsetUnicode = {}".format(netNameOffsetUnicode))
            self._netName = UnpackUnicodeZ('z', scContent[linkContentPos+netNameOffsetUnicode:])[0]
            self._netName = self._netName.decode('utf-16')  
            self._deviceName = UnpackUnicodeZ('z', scContent[linkContentPos+devNameOffsetUnicode:])[0]
            self._deviceName = self._deviceName.decode('utf-16')               
        else:
            self._netName = UnpackZ('z', scContent[linkContentPos+netNameOffset:])[0].decode('ascii')
            self._deviceName = UnpackZ('z', scContent[linkContentPos+devNameOffset:])[0].decode('ascii')

    @property    
    def deviceName(self):
        return self._deviceName

    @property    
    def netName(self):
        return self._netName

    @property    
    def networkProviderType(self):
        return self._networkProviderType



def UnpackZ (fmt, buf) :
    """
    Unpack Null Terminated String
    """
    #logger.debug(bytes(buf))

    while True :
        pos = fmt.find ('z')
        if pos < 0 :
            break
        z_start = struct.calcsize (fmt[:pos])
        z_len = buf[z_start:].find(b'\0')
        #logger.debug(z_len)
        fmt = '%s%dsx%s' % (fmt[:pos], z_len, fmt[pos+1:])
        #logger.debug("fmt='{}', len={}".format(fmt, z_len))
    fmtlen = struct.calcsize(fmt)
    return struct.unpack (fmt, buf[0:fmtlen])


def UnpackUnicodeZ (fmt, buf) :
    """
    Unpack Null Terminated String
    """
    #logger.debug(bytes(buf))
    while True :
        pos = fmt.find ('z')
        if pos < 0 :
            break
        z_start = struct.calcsize (fmt[:pos])
        # look for null bytes by pairs
        z_len = 0
        for i in range(z_start,len(buf),2):
            if buf[i:i+2] == b'\0\0':
                z_len = i-z_start
                break

        fmt = '%s%dsxx%s' % (fmt[:pos], z_len, fmt[pos+1:])
       # logger.debug("fmt='{}', len={}".format(fmt, z_len))
    fmtlen = struct.calcsize(fmt)
    return struct.unpack (fmt, buf[0:fmtlen])
```

I hope this helps others as well.
Thanks

Answer (score 6):

I didn't really like any of the answers available because I didn't want to keep importing more and more libraries and the 'shell' option was spotty on my test machines. I opted for reading the ".lnk" in and then using a regular expression to read out the path. For my purposes, I am looking for pdf files that were recently opened and then reading the content of those files:

```
# Example file path to the shortcut
shortcut = "shortcutFileName.lnk"

# Open the lnk file using the ISO-8859-1 encoder to avoid errors for special characters
lnkFile = open(shortcut, 'r', encoding = "ISO-8859-1")

# Use a regular expression to parse out the pdf file on C:\
filePath = re.findall("C:.*?pdf", lnkFile.read(), flags=re.DOTALL)

# Close File
lnkFile.close()

# Read the pdf at the lnk Target
pdfFile = open(tmpFilePath[0], 'rb')
```

#### Comments:

Obviously this works for `pdf` but needs to specify other file extensions accordingly.

Comment: I like this approach;  it doesn't require windows shells, or using WSL ... or creating classes and all.  Thanks.

Comment: nice approach! However with some shortcuts you may get two matches, and first one will be hardly usable. So I've tuned your expression to a more sophisticated one `[a-zA-Z]:[\\\\/][ \\S]*?\.pdf` to avoid matching against `0x00`

Comment: After some evaluation I tend to think the approach with parsing isn't generic enough to be used in all cases. For instance, it fails, when only relative path is present in a lnk-file (like `..\\..\\..\\..\\..\\..\\Program Files\\ImageGlass\\ImageGlass.exe`), which is stored there in wide chars (may be produced by a msi-installer). So I would switch to another solution like `LnkParse3` or something similar.

Answer (score 2):

A more stable solution in python, using powershell to read the target path from the .lnk file.

- using only standard libraries avoids introducing extra dependencies such as win32com
- this approach works with the .lnks that failed with jared's answer, [more details](https://gist.github.com/Winand/997ed38269e899eb561991a0c663fa49)
- we avoid directly reading the file, which felt hacky, and sometimes failed

```py
import subprocess


def get_target(link_path) -> (str, str):
    """
    Get the target & args of a Windows shortcut (.lnk)
    :param link_path: The Path or string-path to the shortcut, e.g. "C:\\Users\\Public\\Desktop\\My Shortcut.lnk"
    :return: A tuple of the target and arguments, e.g. ("C:\\Program Files\\My Program.exe", "--my-arg")
    """
    # get_target implementation by hannes, https://gist.github.com/Winand/997ed38269e899eb561991a0c663fa49
    ps_command = \
        "$WSShell = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell;" \
        "$Shortcut = $WSShell.CreateShortcut(\"" + str(link_path) + "\"); " \
        "Write-Host $Shortcut.TargetPath ';' $shortcut.Arguments "
    output = subprocess.run(["powershell.exe", ps_command], capture_output=True)
    raw = output.stdout.decode('utf-8')
    launch_path, args = [x.strip() for x in raw.split(';', 1)]
    return launch_path, args

# to test
shortcut_file = r"C:\Users\REPLACE_WITH_USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Accessibility\Narrator.lnk"
a, args = get_target(shortcut_file)
print(a)  # C:\WINDOWS\system32\narrator.exe
```

(you can remove -> typehinting to get it to work in older python versions)

I did notice this is slow when running on lots of shortcuts. You could use jareds method, check if the result is None, and if so, run this code to get the target path.

Answer (score 1):

The nice approach with direct regex-based parsing (proposed in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62459510/536172)) didn't work reliable for all shortcuts in my case. Some of them have only relative path like `..\\..\\..\\..\\..\\..\\Program Files\\ImageGlass\\ImageGlass.exe` (produced by msi-installer), and it is stored with wide chars, which are tricky to handle in Python.
So I've discovered a Python module [LnkParse3](https://github.com/Matmaus/LnkParse3), which is easy to use and meets my needs.
Here is a sample script to show target of a lnk-file passed as first argument:

```
import LnkParse3
import sys

with open(sys.argv[1], 'rb') as indata:
    lnk = LnkParse3.lnk_file(indata)
    print(lnk.lnk_command)
```

Answer (score 0):

I arrived at this thread looking for a way to parse a ".lnk" file and get the target file name.

I found another very simple solution:

```
pip install comtypes
```

Then

```
from comtypes.client import CreateObject
from comtypes.persist import IPersistFile
from comtypes.shelllink import ShellLink

# MAKE SURE THIS VAT CONTAINS A STRING AND NOT AN OBJECT OF 'PATH'
# I spent too much time figuring out the problem with .load(..) function ahead
pathStr="c:\folder\yourlink.lnk"

s = CreateObject(ShellLink)
p = s.QueryInterface(IPersistFile)
p.Load(pathStr, False)
print(s.GetPath())
print(s.GetArguments())
print(s.GetWorkingDirectory())
print(s.GetIconLocation())
try:
    # the GetDescription create exception in some of the links
    print(s.GetDescription())
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
print(s.Hotkey)
print(s.ShowCmd)
```

Based on this great answer...
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43856809/2992810

Answer (score -1):

It's easy as opening ".exe" file. Here also, we are going to use the `os` module for this. You just have to create a shortcut `.lnk` and store it in any folder of your choice. Then, in any Python file, first import the `os` module (already installed, just import). Then, use a variable, say `path`, and assign it a string value containing the location of your `.lnk` file. Just create a shortcut of your desired application. At last, we will use `os.startfile()`
to open our shortcut.

Points to remember:

1. The location should be within double inverted commas.
2. Most important, open Properties. Then, under that, open "Details". There, you can get the exact name of your shortcut. Please write that name with ".lnk" at last.

Now, you have completed the procedure. I hope it helps you. For additional assistance, I am  leaving my code for this at the bottom.

```py
import os

path = "C:\\Users\\hello\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Shortcuts\\OneNote for Windows 10.lnk"

os.startfile(path)
```

In my code, I used `path` as variable and I had created a shortcut for OneNote. In path, I defined the location of OneNote's shortcut. So when I use `os.startfile(path)`, the `os` module is going to open my shortcut file defined in variable path.

Comment: Python doesn't care particularly whether you use single or double quotes. Calling them "inverted commas" is kind of misleading (curly quotes look like inverted commas; proper ASCII quotes not so much). For Windows path names, using raw strings (`r'C:\horrible\Windows\pain'` with an `r` before the opening quote) often makes more sense than doubling every backslash; though for compatibility, Windows in fact allows you to replace the backslashes with forward slashes, too.

Comment: Anyway, the question is how to resolve the link, not how to open it.

Answer (score -1):

this job is possible without any modules, doing this will return a b string having the destination of the shortcut file. Basically what you do is you open the file in read binary mode (`rb` mode). This is the code to accomplish this task:

```
with open('programs.lnk - Copy','rb') as f:
    destination=f.read()
```

i am currently using python 3.9.2, in case you face problems with this, just tell me and i will try to fix it.