# Python - How to read App's path (Without knowing it)

Tags: python, dictionary, desktop

Just learned that Python can open files such as `*.txt` and more. Isn't that amazing?

I want to be able to read a text (*.txt) file. This is a dictionary of a game that is on desktop. I don't really know the path of the game.

Is there a way that to determine the path of that game on desktop?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question. What does *"the file is in dictionary of a game"* mean? Is your problem finding the location of the file, or is your problem opening the file?

Comment: @Aran-Fey , Sorry , That was my bad sir, My question is "How could I find a path of a game ( Or anything ) Thats on desktop (Shortcut of it Ofcourse).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading the target of a .lnk file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/397125/reading-the-target-of-a-lnk-file-in-python)

Comment: it means that you want to find a path of original file from its shortcut or find out what is the Desktop path ?