# how can i find the path to a file by its shortcut?

Tags: python

if I have the name of a shortcut to file can I find the path to this specific file?
I have the shortcut name by I cannot find the path to its original file
is there any code that can get me to the original file?

```
shortcut = filename
```

how can I get the path to its original file location?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading the target of a .lnk file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/397125/reading-the-target-of-a-lnk-file-in-python)

Comment: I can't understand the way they used if it possible can you please help me with that

Comment: It's in the second part of the first answer, replace `t:\\test.lnk` with the path to your shortcut and you can get the path with `shortcut.Targetpath`

Comment: can i do the same only with the name of the shortcut?