# How to open .lnk files with python

Tags: python

Please tell me how to open `.lnk` files

it is not opening this:

```
import webbrowser as wb
wb.open('dir_path/ Microsoft Edge.lnk')
```

But when i do this:

```
import webbrowser as wb
wb.open('dir_path/ picture.png')
```

or any thing else it opens the path

Comment: Do you mean .ink or .lnk files? What file type are these anyway?

Comment: I think you mean `.lnk`. Those are windows shortcut files. Python cannot open and read their content as they only hold reference to another file on your machine. Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/397125/reading-the-target-of-a-lnk-file-in-python

Comment: Thank you very much. I wrote the file extension as .ink but it is .lnk