# how to create a windows shortcut to a folder in python

Tags: python, windows, shortcut

My problem is that i can't find a solution to create a shortcut to an folder with python. Only to a file, code example:

```
shell = Dispatch('WScript.Shell')
shortcut = shell.CreateShortCut(path)
shortcut.Targetpath = target
shortcut.save()
```

But I need a shortcut to a whole folder.

My target example is:

`C:/Users`and `C:/Users/user/Downloads`

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/397125

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the below code to create shortcut to a directory

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch

path = r"C:\Users\user\Downloads\shortcut.lnk"  #This is where the shortcut will be created
target = r"C:\Users\user\Downloads" # directory to which the shortcut is created

shell = Dispatch('WScript.Shell')
shortcut = shell.CreateShortCut(path)
shortcut.Targetpath = target
shortcut.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

**Backslashes** (`\`) must be used in `shortcut.Targetpath` for shortcuts to work correctly for folders.